# Objects rotating around another object keep accelerating

Tags: c++, rotation, sfml

Ok so I'm still new to programming and I've been trying to work on a scene graph and whenever I rotate an object its children keep accelerating around it when all I want  them to do is rotate around the parent object at the same speed it (the parent object) is rotating.

This is what makes them rotate

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Q) == true)
{
    if (Entity != nullptr)
    {
    Entity->theSprite.rotate(-10);
    if (Entity->isParent == true)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < Entity->listofChildren.size(); i++)
            {
            Entity->listofChildren.at(i)->theSprite.rotate(-10);
            Entity->listofChildren.at(i)->theSprite.setPosition(rotateAround(Entity, Entity->listofChildren.at(i)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what calculates the rotation

```
sf::Vector2f winMan::rotateAround(_Entity* toRotateAround, _Entity* toRotate)
{
    sf::Vector2f newPos;
    sf::Vector2f toRotateAroundpos = toRotateAround->theSprite.getPosition();
    sf::Vector2f toRotatepos = toRotate->theSprite.getPosition();

    float angle = toRotateAround->theSprite.getRotation() * (_PI / 180);

    newPos.x = cos(angle) * (toRotatepos.x - toRotateAroundpos.x) - sin(angle) * (toRotatepos.y - toRotateAroundpos.y) + toRotateAroundpos.x;
    newPos.y = sin(angle) * (toRotatepos.x - toRotateAroundpos.x) + cos(angle) * (toRotatepos.y - toRotateAroundpos.y) + toRotateAroundpos.y;

    return newPos;
}
```

I've been trying to figure out why this happens and my guess is that it just keeps adding up every frame but I don't know how to make it stop :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you first rotate the parent in

```
Entity->theSprite.rotate(-10);
```

and then later use the rotation of this parent to determine the rotation angle for the children here

```
float angle = toRotateAround->theSprite.getRotation() * (_PI / 180);
```

Lets go through what the program calculates:

1. iteration: ParentAngle = -10 -> Rotation of the children plus -10 -> -10
2. iteration: ParentAngle = -20 -> Rotation of the children plus -20 -> -30
3. iteration: ParentAngle = -30 -> Rotation of the children plus -30 -> -60

Instead of using the current angle of the parent sprite as a reference you should pass the rotation value directly into the function `rotateAround`